# Adding Vite to (kinda) legacy Vue2-JSX Project

Tags: vuejs2, frontend, jsx, vite, monorepo

I'm working on this somewhat legacy project that was build using Vue2's `render(h){}` function to render components, so it basically works as jsx, even though the components are `.js`. To complicate things, it's built using a Monorepo architecture vie yarn-Workspaces, where all the packages work togheter to build 1 system, instead of just being their own separate worlds as I understand is usual.

We want to implement Vite to help address some issues:

- the whole code is loaded into the users device, no matter what they access, everything is downloaded
- The code ins't minified for production, meaning, among other things, it's totally legible for outsiders, compromising the secutiry of it
- data-cy and data-test aren't removed from production code

Given the context, my problem is that I have no idea how to implement this correctly, plugin-vue2-jsx for vite seems to be poorly maintained from my research, the architecture doesn't seem to fit and I couldn't get it to work yet, so I came for help.

our file structure is something like this:

project
|-packages
|-|-core
|-|-package-1
|-|-package-2
|-|-package-3
|-|-shared

And the files are like this:

```
export const Component = {
name: "Component",

data: () => ({
  component_name: "Name"
}),

methods: {
  doComponentStuff() {
    return
  }
},

render (h) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Component</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Component
```

I tried applying vite to my legacy project and the project wont build anymore. I added a vite config file and made the entry-point my existing main.js, when it runs, nothing is rendered, the #app element ins't populated by the Vue App. I also tried creating a Vite project and then migrating my existing code to there, but I cant get a Vite environment that suits the project's needs to work. It needs to support JSX code inside JS files, and also be Vue2 compatible, otherwise we'd have to refactor the whole codebase.